# Bootstrap collapse navbar-collapse not working on angular 8

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4

I tried to use bootstrap collapse navbar-collapse feature on my angular 8 project but after compiling it its not showing the correct output.
I already install:
**bootstrap - 4.3.1** and make changes on **angular.json** file.
**jquery** is also installed on my angular project
Here is the bootstrap snippet i tried to implement it.

**header.component.html**

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">Recipe Book</a>
    </div>
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">Recipe Book</a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a href="#">recipes</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Shoppimg List</a></li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">

        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle">Manage</a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Saving Data</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Fetching Data</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>

      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Guidance needed

Comment: Have you add All Script tag of bootstrap in head tag of index.html file?

Comment: don't use jquery in Angular... use ng-bootstrap, md-bootstrap or ngx-bootstrap to get the components

Answer (score 1):

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm bg-dark navbar-dark">
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">Recipe Book</a>
    </div>

    <ul class="navbar-nav">
        <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link">Recipes</a></li>
        <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link">Shopping List</a></li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" id="navbardrop">Manage</a>
            <div class="dropdown-menu">
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-item">Save Data</a>
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-item">Fatch Data</a>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: This answer is code only, which is not really helpful; you could improve it by adding an explanation of what was wrong and what you did to make it work.